# Как получить виджеты находящиеся в BoxSizer на wx.Panel?

Tags: python, controls, wxpython

Как получить виджеты находящиеся в BoxSizer на wx.Panel?(WxPython)?

```py
wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE )
self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
bSizer2.Add( self.m_button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


self.m_panel1.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
self.m_panel1.Layout()
bSizer2.Fit( self.m_panel1 )
self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel1, u"a page", False, wx.NullBitmap )

bSizer1.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
self.Layout()

self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение.

```
panel.GetChildren() #Возвращает список виджетов
```